# Crash with id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> after updating to iOS 9.3.1 and Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

I have a task application that show task and subtasks in a list.

Before updating to iOS 9.3.1 and Xcode 7.3 everything went OK but know, I get an error when I try to get `[section objects]` from an `id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` object.

This is my code:

```
NSArray *fetchResult = [Task MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"subtask" withPredicate:subtasksFilter sortedBy:@"subtask" ascending:YES delegate:nil inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]].sections;

NSMutableDictionary *subtasksDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> section in fetchResult){
    [subtasksDictionary setObject:[section objects] forKey:[section name]];
}
```

And this is the error I got:

[image]

It only crash when fetchResult has got more than 1 object.

This is the object section when it crash:

[image]

`Hightrack[1874:378615] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray fetchedObjects]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18089660'`

Comment: Sounds to me like there might be some premature deallocation on some object(s) in fetchResult. Maybe you could try running it via Instruments with Zombie mode enabled?

Comment: It is very difficult to detect that, I have edited my question with a screenshot of the object section. As you can see, sectionObjects is nil but numberOfObjects is 1. Is it normal? When sectionObjects is not nil, and only one fetch the predicate, the number of objects is also 1 but it doesn't crash.

Comment: Did you find the reason of this? Encountering this on macOS

Comment: No, sorry. I wasn't able to fix it.